# Windows Phone 7 in-app purchases

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

What is the status of Windows Phone 7 regarding in-app purchases? Is it accessible for developers yet?

Additionally is any plug-in for PhoneGap available?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement yourself already, if you already have the relevant infrastructure in place for handling card payments - in fact Pizza Hut do have quite a good app for ordering and paying for pizza all on the phone (at least in the UK market) - it's just ironic that the quality of their pizzas isn't as high as the app...