# WP7 - selling extensions

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I'm trying to create some application for Windows Phone >= 7.1
During plannin my work and specyfiong technical requirements I've come across one problem.
I wan't to have free application with basic functionality. And then it should be extendable with some non-free extensions (dlls?, databases?, SaaS?)
Is it possible at the moment to use some MS api/app/etc. to be able to publish such extensions and sell them? What is the best way to do this if there is more than one solution?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 in-app purchases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10828705/50447)

Answer (score 1):

As of right now (June 2012), in-app purchases are not supported. Your only choices, then are being a paid app and supporting trial mode.

Comment: Or releasing two; a limited functionality free app and a paid app.

Comment: @sachleen - Why would you do that when the marketplace supports trials? The trial doesn't have to be time based, it can simply adjust it's features.

Comment: Ah I did not know that. I come from iOS, I'm relatively new to WP7. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RichardSzalay culture - consumers *might not* realise that a paid app's trial mode is the same as a free version (for example, it may be add supported, or limit some functions) - also, by being "free", it will show up in additional places in the marketplace.

Comment: The support for in-app purchases will most likely come with WP8. Releasing the free + paid app combo is sometimes better than trial (this way you can get more attention from users, because the app appears on the free app list)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this at present is to handle the additional purchases yourself.

You'd have to set up a website which customers could create an account on and purchase extensions through, then have them also log into your app with those account details to determine what additional data to download or functions to enable.

You could be smart and include the website functionality into your app with a browser control. Take a look at the Amazon Kindle app for an example of how they accomplish it.